# How to fix ''if , else '' command in Python?

Tags: python

```
name = ('Dev')
>>> print (name)
Dev
>>> if name == 'pork' : print('number 1') else : print('number2')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if name == 'pork' : print('number 1')

>>> else : print('n')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .
```

This sort of script worked before. I restarted the shell like 3 times , please help I have no idea on what to do

This is one of my first scripts, I just started coding and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
name = ('Dev')
>>> print (name)
Dev
>>> if name == 'pork' : print('number 1') else : print('number2')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if name == 'pork' : print('number 1')

>>> else : print('n')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The result should have been the shell saying 'n' since that was my 'else' command

Comment: Read about indentations in python before coding. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments

Comment: You can't put the `else:` part on the same line; Python requires each part of the `if` statement to go on a line of its own. Blocks also go on their own line, indented, unless it is a single simple statement.

Comment: Why don't you write an actual script, in a file, with multiple lines like normal Python code, rather than trying to use complex one-liners in the interactive shell?

Comment: If you are working in the interactive interpreter, then don't use a double newline, that ends a block.

Comment: The problem is  , I don't actually know how to separate statements, like make a new line. What's the key?

Comment: Just press enter after the ":", it'll go down to a new line

Comment: Please read flow controls in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=statement#if-statements

Comment: @NipunSampath doesn't work. I pressed the '':'' and I didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to order this way (code as you say it):

```
>>> print('number 1') if name == 'pork' else print('number2')
```

This prints `'number1'` if `name` is `'pork'` else `'number2'`.

On multiple lines, you should focus on *indentation*:

```
>>> if name == 'pork':                                      
...     print('number1')                                    
... else:                                                   
...     print('number2')                                    
...
```

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but I did a similar script a while ago with the same order and it worked so I don't see why it wouldn't now

Comment: @DevNord Probably because it was in an actual script and you used *indentation*, which is very necessary in Python.

Comment: Ok , but how do I use indentation now? I honestly don't know. Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

If you try running make operator ternary:

A if condition else B

for exemple:

```
print('Hello Word') if True else print('Ola Mundo')
```

Comment: *"operator ternary"*? Which operator is used ternary?

Comment: python has no ternary operator, but I think this would be an analogy to ternary operators